# What does the commutator subgroup of a knot group "look like"?

Tags: geometric-topology, knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology

For $X = S^3 - K$ a knot complement, the abelianization $$1 \to [\pi_1(X),\pi_1(X)] \to \pi_1(X) \to \mathbb{Z} \to 1$$ has a right split, where $\mathbb{Z} \cong \pi_1(X)^{ab}$ is realized by a meridian loop. This yields the semidirect product $\pi_1(X) \cong [\pi_1,\pi_1] \rtimes \mathbb{Z}$.

**My question is:** how do I see the commutator subgroup geometrically? I.e. the $\mathbb{Z}$ subgroup is a meridian loop as I said. Is there some similar geometric description of the commutator subgroup?

When $X$ is fibered, the infinite cyclic cover, which is the cover corresponding to $[\pi_1,\pi_1] \leq \pi_1(X)$, deformation retracts to the fiber surface (I think). So the commutator subgroup is just the fundamental group of the fiber surface (which in particular is a free group). Can we say anything when the knot is not fibered? Like maybe you get the fundamental group of a minimal genus Seifert surface?

Edit: according to a theorem of Stallings (1962), the subgroup $[\pi_1,\pi_1]$ is finitely generated if and only if $K$ is fibered. So in the non-fibered case, this subgroup is going to be pretty wild. Is there anything we can still understand about it? Is it still a free group?

Comment: The commutator subgroup is the fundamental group of the infinite cyclic cover (so you're correct that it's the fundamental group of a fiber surface for a fibered knot).  In general things are more complicated -- I think you can use the HNN extension presentation from an incompressible Seifert surface in a straightforward way, since the kernel of the abelianization corresponds to words with a net-$0$ number of the stable letter.  (I sort of think of what happens as being loops in the infinite cyclic cover getting "caught" by singularities along a "monodromy" of a Seifert surface.)

Comment: It generates $\pi_1$ normally, but not straight up I don't think. I have to choose which meridional loop represents $\mathbb{Z}$ since they're not all homotopic rel a basepoint, but once I've made that choice shouldn't it just work?

Comment: Ah you are right sorry, I shouldn't be posting before drinking coffee. I've deleted my earlier comment.

Comment: You have actually already given an answer in your own question: the infinite cyclic cover is the covering corresponding to $[\pi_1(X),\pi_1(X)]$, *and therefore* $[\pi_1(X),\pi_1(X)]$ is isomorphic to the fundamental group of the infinite cyclic cover. Perhaps, though, you might also be asking how to geometrically understand the infinite cyclic cover (and its fundamental group)?

Comment: @LeeMosher I think what I was wondering was more if one could "see" $[\pi_1,\pi_1]$ in the knot complement, in the way that you just see it as a fiber surface for a fibered knot. But understanding the infinite cyclic cover for non-fibered knots would also be good.

Comment: By the way, Rolfsen's book "Knot Theory" has a nice discussion of the infinite cyclic cover of a knot, with tools for visualizing it included. His discussion is tailored towards "seeing" the Alexander polynomial, but one could easily adapt that discussion to "seeing" $[\pi_1,\pi_1]$.